# Prevent an iframe from playing audio

Tags: html, iframe

On our website we will be allowing `iframe` modules from other sites to display on our company's webpage. We want to use `iframe` [sandboxing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) to prevent these modules from doing anything crazy like phishing attacks, but I can't seem to find a way to prevent the `iframe` from playing annoying audio.

```
<iframe sandbox=''>
  // Code from other site injected here
  // May contain something like this: <audio src='...' autoplay='true' />
  // May play sound some other way
  // Don't let any sound come out of this iframe!
</iframe>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: will you have any control over the iframe contents, e.g., by creating their content dynamically or using postMessage?

Comment: @fgshepard Once the `iframe` is loaded I can definitely modify the contents of it. We have control of the parent `document` so I guess we could check regularly for any changes in the `iframe` and disable stuff?

Comment: If it's from another domain you won't be able to touch the contents of the iframe directly.

Comment: @fgshepard Good to know, I was not aware of this.

Comment: you could interact with the contents using window.postMessage, but this would require the owner of the iframe content to listen for your messages and respond accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like in FireFox it may be:

Updated link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/mute_event

broken link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/mute

To save you the trouble of clicking the link:

The mute() method of the HTMLIFrameElement mutes any audio playing in the browser .

```
var browser = document.querySelector('iframe');

browser.mute();
```

Comment: This does not exists anymore.